# Different result after joining new table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relational-database

My fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mALNg1YXoWJhf1Wbdmhekz/5)

I tried to repair the second query and return the same result as in the first query because products with id in `(1,2,3,4,5)` are all available products, so the results should be the same.

Why am I getting different results in the second query? How can I repair it?

Basically, I want to check what is the total ad_spend during each month for all ads (first query) and for ads which has assigned certain products (second query)

My first query(which return correct result):

```
select min(DATE_FORMAT(ai.date,"%m-%Y")) as date, ROUND(SUM(ai.ad_spend)) as total_ad_spend
                from ad_insight ai 
                group by YEAR(ai.date), MONTH(ai.date) 
                order by ai.date asc;
```

My second query(which return incorrect result):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(ai.date, '%m-%Y') as mmyy,
  MIN(ai.date) as min_date,
  ROUND(SUM(ai.ad_spend)) as total_ad_spend
from ad_insight as ai
join ads_products as ap on ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
where ap.product_id in (1,2,3,4, 5)
group by mmyy
order by min_date
```

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query lies in the fact that the `JOIN` operation will map every matching row of the first table with every matching row of the second table (in a many-to-many fashion), hence the aggregation results in a multiple of the real sum values.

In order to fix this problem, you should:

- first select your "*ad_id*" once (distinctively) from the "*ads_product*" table, given your filtering condition,
- then apply your `JOIN` operation with the first table.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ai.date, '%m-%Y') AS mmyy,
       MIN(ai.date)                  AS min_date,
       ROUND(SUM(ai.ad_spend))       AS total_ad_spend
FROM       ad_insight                        ai
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ad_id 
            FROM ads_products 
            WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)) ap 
        ON ai.ad_id = ap.ad_id
GROUP BY mmyy
ORDER BY min_date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mALNg1YXoWJhf1Wbdmhekz/6).